# Reason behind a problem of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Why does the area under the curve from -1 to 1 of definite integral 2/(1+x^2) equal pi?

I understood how to reach that answer but I don't understand why is it pi since its an area under the bell curve.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @Kuthalingam: Please show your effort. Did you recognize an inverse trig function?

Answer (score 0):

Translating your problem into maths:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{2}{x^2+1}\ \text{d}x = \pi$$

You can take the $2$ outside.

What is the integral of $\dfrac{1}{x^2 + 1}$?

I believe that if you came to the point in which you study areas under curvs, then you must know how to calculate that integral. It is also a "notable integral".